# Change values while a Java Timer is running?

Tags: java

I am trying to change values while my Java timer is running and only keep the values set while the timer is running, however once the timer has a pause i cant seem to change the values back to what they were. Is there some kind of if(timer.isActive) keyword or way of doing this so i can change the values back after the timer is paused/ended? Here is the code i have so far

```
public void tick() {
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){

            velX = player.getX() + 20;
            velY = player.getY() + 20;

        }
    }, 3000, 3000);


    velX = player.getX();
    velY = player.getY();

}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What exactly do you want to to? It might just be me but I feel like you could use a bit more clarification. Perhaps by means of an example?

Comment: some clarification and additional details are required. Please add more details of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: While the timer is running i want to change the value of the velX and velY, and when the timer is paused i want to change the values back to what they were (which is underneath the timer code)

Comment: and exactly is happening when you mean pause.

Comment: When the timer is supposed to pause, the values do not get changed back to what they were, they seem to get added together almost?

Comment: do you mean every time the method tick() gets called you want to re initialize the variables? if possible provide a example code for your issue. for help go to :: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When the timer is over i want to change the values back to what they used to be which is the velX and velY below, i need some kind of way of telling if the timer is active or not

Comment: this does not make sense. basically pause/end of timer means end of run method, which is where you should be resetting the value, but all you are doing in the method is setting the values.